# Server doesn't listen to requests

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

as a part of my homework I have to build two classes one listener and one that is making the requests to the server (the server is already written by my teacher and I don't know how code looks like). In theory: The server that I'm connected to should reply with the exact same requests I sent to him. But in practice I get nothing back.

```java
public class Listenerthread extends Thread {
    Socket s;
    Scanner answerServer;

    public Listenerthread(Socket socket) {
        this.s = socket;
        this.answerServer = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())));
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Listening to the responses from the server......");
        while (true) {
            if (answerServer.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(answerServer.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Mainthread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Socket s = new Socket("someServer", 9999);
        Listenerthread server = new Listenerthread(s);
        server.start();
        if (s.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected");
        }
        String req = "Heyyy mate";  // server should sent me this back
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        pw.println(req);
        pw.flush();
        //pw.close();
        //s.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: What server are you connecting to? Where is the code for the server? All you have there is a `Socket` that's acting as a client.

Comment: I'm connecting to a server in my school. I have no idea what kind of server this is. My teachner never showed me how the servercode looks like, but he said that my requests are finding the server and that the server is replying to me. So I gues something is wrong with my understanding of threads.

Comment: If the server is already written and listening, yo don't need to write any server and don't even need any thread. All you need is a main method sending a line to the server and reading the answer. And of course, you must not close the socket as soon as you've sent your request, as you're doing it now: if the socket is closed, you can't receive anything from its input stream.

Comment: @quinzo Your comment here might make my answer invalid, though I hope it is still useful. Your question and code make it look like you are writing a client and server. You might want to change it to reflect the fact that you say you are not responsible for the server, and that you are merely connecting to a pre-existing server. Your code even looks like an attempt to write a server, as you call things "server", "Serverthread", and output "Server is running".

Comment: @Aaron Did some edits. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @JBNizet in my previous homework I did it just like that. But this time I have to build a Thread that is permanently listening to my requests.

Comment: `pw.close();` ends up closing the output stream returned by `Socket.getOutputStream()`. As @JBNizet stated, this prevents you from receiving anything.

Comment: @quinzo It very well may have worked in previous homeworks. However, when it comes to multithreaded programming, especially when combining it with network communication like this, you cannot guarantee that things happen in the order you expect them to happen in. It could work in one homework but not in the next, or work one day but not the next day. As soon as you introduce interactions between threads, you cannot rely on the threads having any specific timeline between them and you need to program accordingly. "Accordingly" being a topic which could feed many more questions and answers.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you very much but this also didn't help me.

Comment: @Aaron do you have any helpful links I can look up for my problem or some improvements to my code? I'm very new to thread and nework programming.

Comment: Maybe the server never sends back a new line, and thus nextLine() never completes. What happens when you just print `answerServer.next()`?

Comment: Stil no response. I also tried to run the Listenerthread before the Mainthread with the sleep() method but still no progress :/

Comment: @quinzo What is the output that you get from the program? Do you see the "Connected" output? Do you see the "Listening to responses from the server"? As JBNizet suggested, maybe there's a problem with the server - you could try to write your own if you feel comfortable with that. Also, do you know what is going on inside that `while(true)` loop? Maybe it could use some debug output, such as `System.out.println("checking again");`, though that might spam you with tons of lines of "checking again".

Comment: @Aaron Yes I‘m getting the ‚connected‘ message and the while loop spamms me with ‚checking again‘

Comment: @quinzo As for the example you asked for, there is an official example of practically the same thing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: @quinzo However, it is not difficult to tell if it looks like a student copies from such examples, and that example is a well known one, so your teacher will probably notice if you copy that work directly. So you would be wise to look at it to learn from and then continue working on your own without seeing them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Update: A comment that OP left on the question after I started writing this answer shows that OP does not actually need to handle the server side of the communications. I will leave this answer for now in case it could still be useful.

---

When you have a client/server model, you should use a `ServerSocket` on the server side, as you alluded to in your question but then do not appear to have done in your code.

[ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)

Here is a `ServerSocket` example that may clear that up.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket;

public void serverSocketTest()
{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
    // each of the below methods will happen on separate threads
    new Thread(this::serverSideAcceptConnectionFromClient).start();
    new Thread(this::clientSideConnectToServer).start();
}

public void clientSideConnectToServer()
{
    try {
        System.out.println("Client is trying to connect to server...");
        Socket connectionToServer = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        OutputStream thisGoesToTheServer = connectionToServer.getOutputStream();
        InputStream thisIsDataComingFromServer = connectionToServer.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("Client successfully connected to server.");
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Connection to server failed. (" + ex + ")");
    }
}

public void serverSideAcceptConnectionFromClient()
{
    try {
        System.out.println("Server is listening for potential clients...");
        Socket connectionFromClient = serverSocket.accept();
        InputStream thisIsDataComingFromClient = connectionFromClient.getInputStream();
        OutputStream thisIsGoesBackOutToClient = connectionFromClient.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Server accepted a client");
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error while listening for clients. (" + ex + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway thank you very much. I'm sure that this will be helpful for me in the future :)